# Moving a View Up

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Ok, this might sound simple, but somehow I can't get this function to work .

```
- (void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.height);
    if (movedUp)
    {
        NSLog(@"test Moved Up");
        rect.origin.y += 60;
        rect.size.height -= 300;
    }
    self.view.frame = rect ;
    NSLog(@"%f after:",self.view.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

All the NSLogs are printing results fine and "Test Moved Up" appears so I know there is nothing wrong upstream .

This function is part of the implementation file of my MainViewController ( which manages the root view of my Window app ) .

I assume I have to call : **self.view.frame**, right ?

No error or warning appears, but it just doesn`t move despite printing out the logs correctly ..

Edit, this is the hierarchy in IB :

[image]

---

Edit again : I'm actually wondering if I'm allowed to move that view up, are we allowed to move views up if they are at the top of the hierarchy ? Then what would be revealed behind ?

Comment: You are moving the view down by 60 pixels and not moving up.

Comment: alright, wrong side, but it should still be moving, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing just the three animation messages.

If it moves (I think it won't, but ...)

1. Try passing in @"moveup" as the first argument to beginAnimations
2. Try using setAnimationCurve

If it doesn't move

1. Is the view inside another view that sets a layout for this view?
2. Are you calling this inside the main thread (not in a background thread)

EDIT: Update

You shouldn't need to do this, but try

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

If that doesn't work, try it on the window.  Changing the frame is supposed to do this automatically.

Comment: So, it doesn`t move just removing the three animation messages . The View is not inside any other view, it does however contains views inside . As far as I know this is executing inside the main thread . See diagram here : https://cacoo.com/diagrams/FFej49F5nTWCca4o

Comment: What in your app causes this to be called?

Comment: The button in the scroll view

Comment: [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; didn`t work unfortunately . When you say try it on the window it would be as simple as : [self.window setNeedsDisplay] right ? because that`s giving me : "Request for member "window" is something not a structure or union"

Comment: [self.view.window setNeedsDisplay] -- probably won't work. Are you sure that this viewcontroller is set up correctly. Does any other change to the view work?

Comment: Hey Lou, thanks for your help on this, the [self.view.window setNeedsDisplay] didn`t work either . The ViewController is connected to the App Delegate in the referencing outlet and to the Main View as its outlet. I also have a modal View Transition on this ViewController an it works just fine :( I just don`t see what else it could be !